# Deeplinking: nickname field crashing Uber App

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to deeplink my app with the Uber App. This is the code I'm using as test:

```
String uri = "uber://?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[latitude]=-23.56491&dropoff[longitude]=-46.652005&dropoff[formatted_address]=Av Paulista, 1000 - Bela Vista&dropoff[nickname]=Meeting: Av Paulista, 1000 - Bela Vista";

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that the ":" in "dropoff[nickname]=Meeting: Av Paulista, 1000 - Bela Vista" crashes the Uber App (the app opens, the uber loading screen appears for a while and then the app crashes). If I remove the ":", it works smoothly.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` is a reserved character in the URI scheme and may need to be `%`-encoded (i.e. as `%3A`).

(There are other reserved characters in your URI, such as `[` and `]`, but it may be that the Uber app is sensitive to `:` for some reason. I don't believe you should really have to encode the `:` because it can't act as a delimiter in the position that it is, but it's worth a try).

See [RFC 3986 section on percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12) and the nearby section on reserved characters.

Comment: Thanks davmac! Using %3A worked, but its really weird that only the ":" needs to be encoded. Anyway, it worked! :)